# Pandas Drop rows if String has numeric (floats of 4 decimals/5 numbers)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a long list dataframe that has texts similar to the example provided in the image. dataframe is called gbs2. I want to `gbs2.drop` rows with numerical values that has 4 decimal places or 5 numbers ("1.2345" or "12345")
Code used:

```
name = pd.Series(['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'])
Produced_Qty = pd.Series(['ABC 1.407', 'NOP 1.6345', 'XYZ 1.3144/1.7523 ect'])
Passed_Qty = pd.Series([499768, 756662, 301297])

gbs2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name,
                     'Produced Qty': Produced_Qty,
                     'Passed Qty':Passed_Qty})
gbs2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqzDV.png)

In this case, Product B and Product C should be dropped. My original case which I cannot post has longer texts where the interested number is in the middle, but has many words from the start and end of the string.

I could not find ways to identify numerical values in a string that has both alphabets and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\d+.\d{4}` to match a floating point number with 4 decimals and `\d{5}` for a number with 5 digits combined with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then invert the boolean with `~` and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = gbs2.loc[~gbs2['Produced Qty'].str.contains(r'\d+.\d{4}|\d{5}')]
```

Output:

```
        Name Produced Qty  Passed Qty
0  Product A    ABC 1.407      499768
```

If you want to match exactly 4/5 digits and no more, you additionally have to ensure the pattern is not having extra digits around it, then use `'(?<!\d)(?:\d+.\d{4}|\d{5})(?!\d)'`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5EbTs/1)

Comment: oh my bad. sorry. that is indeed what i requested. I was confused with my other work

Comment: @Bing no worries :) In any case, you can remove the `~` to select the matching rows

Comment: Ya I figured that. It was cool when I tried it. Really Appreciate it.